# Is it possible to set switch button to true via function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

i got an switch button in my HTML part.It uses "checked ng-click",
 "ng-modal" and uses the css class "switch" from https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/switch

So my problem is i ve got a function at my Controller, which needs to change the button from false to true. 
For the logic it works by setting the ng-modal to true, but i still need to get the button set as true in view. 
Is there a way to do this? 
Something like "set ng-click as true" or something?

```html
<span style='float: right;' class='hidden-print'>
    <span class='roundButtonsInProject' style='color: white'>dynamische Ansicht</span>
    <label class='switch'>
        <input checked ng-click="idler()" ng-model='dynamicView' type='checkbox'>
        <span class='slider round'></span>
    </label>
</span>
```

So i just need the button act like being clicked

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `switch` class in the AngularJS Material CSS. The AngularJS Material framework does not use `<input>` elements when it implements its `md-switch` directive. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score -1):

Just use **ng-checked**

```
  <md-switch ng-model="data.cb6" aria-label="Switch 6"
             ng-change="onChange(data.cb6)" ng-checked="true">
    Switch 6 message: {{ message }}
  </md-switch>
```

I believe this will help.

Comment: So i set an id on my button and use 
expect(element(by.id('idleCheck')).getAttribute('checked')).toBeTruthy();
in my js file, but it dosnt work.

Comment: Don't use `ng-model` and `ng-checked` together. The `ng-model` directive is for two-way binding and `ng-checked` is for one-way binding.